# AWS Glue ETL job removing partition keys from file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am writing an AWS Glue ETL job. It is really simple, just reading in some s3 files, creating a dynamic frame, partitioning based on a few keys, and then writing that dynamic frame to another s3 bucket. However, when the transformation happens, the partition keys are stripped from the output file. I would like to retain these keys, and I am having a difficult time from the documentation figuring out if that is possible. Any information would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

At this point, I've just been scouring the documentation looking for a potential solution, haven't found anything relevant, but it's possible I missed it.

Comment: Which method are you using to write that dataframe back to s3 ?

Comment: @arthurq I am using glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options

Comment: Well, if there is a way is by using a specific option on the connection_optios parameter but the docs are too sparse about it. I would suggest duplicating the column with maybe _partition suffixes and using this copy to partition. That way you keep the original columns.

Comment: @arthurq thanks, that is a good suggestion! I'll let you know if I end up trying it

Comment: @HaleyKirk Please include the code which writes to S3, the dynamicframe schema, and column names to partition on.